# How to zip a pdf or ppt file using jszip?

Tags: javascript, zip, jszip

I want zip a pdf or some other format like excel, ppt etc using jszip.

How to zip this format in jszip?

My code is as below

```
<BODY>
  <a id ='file' href="data/some.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=432628">Some.pdf</a>
  <input id="button" type="button" onclick="create_zip()" value="Create Zip"></input>
</BODY>
<SCRIPT>
        function create_zip() {
        var data = document.getElementById('file');
            var zip = new JSZip();
            zip.add(data, {base64: true});
            content = zip.generate();
            location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
        }
</SCRIPT>
```

What I want is that I will get the path of the file from the a element in the html. I want to zip the pdf using jszip

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm33E/)

Answer (score 2):

[JSZipUtils](https://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/documentation/api/getbinarycontent.html) may be useful for you. This is the example for the documentation:

```
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("path/to/picture.png", function (err, data) {
    if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle the error
    }
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file("picture.png", data, {binary:true});
}
```

Which can be easily adapted to your case:

```
function create_zip() {
    var url = document.getElementById('file').href;
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            throw err; // or handle the error
        }
        var zip = new JSZip();
        zip.file("Some.pdf", data, {binary:true});
        content = zip.generate();
     }
}
```